# Access DataTemplate from ResourceDictionary when DataTemplate doesn't have a key, only TargetType

Tags: wpf, code-behind, resourcedictionary, targettype

I have a ResouceDictionary defined in XAML with codebehind. I need to define some view-specific behaviors with mouse-events and databinding, and for that I need to access some elements defined inside a DataTemplate.

The problem is, the DataTemplate doesn't have a Key it only has a TargetType (that is needed so WPF will automatically use it for the given type).

So, how can I access the DataTemplate from codebehind?

EDIT:

If I put a breakpoint somewhere in the constructor, I can see that the template for my ViewModel is there. It seems that ResourceDictionary.Keys property is an array of objects, and the key I want to access (or the corresponding value, actually) is like this in the debugger:

```
{DataTemplateKey(Company.Application.ViewModels.TargetViewModel)}
```

XAML:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="escala">10</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="raio">20</sys:Double>
<EllipseGeometry x:Key="geometriacirculo"
    RadiusX="{StaticResource raio}"
    RadiusY="{StaticResource raio}"/>
<ScaleTransform x:Key="transform" ScaleX="{StaticResource escala}" ScaleY="{StaticResource escala}" />
<ap:NormalConverter x:Key="NormalConverter"/>   
<ap:BitmapToSource x:Key="BitmapToSource"/>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TelaColetaViewModel}">
        <.....
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class TelaColetaTemplate : ResourceDictionary
{

    EllipseGeometry _geometria_circulo;
    ScaleTransform _scale_transform;
    Grid GridZoom;
    Path CirculoGuia;

    double _escala;

    Point? _ponto_clicado_norm;     

    public TelaColetaTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // three following lines work, accessing them with key, no problem
        _geometria_circulo = (EllipseGeometry)this["geometriacirculo"];
        _scale_transform = (ScaleTransform)this["transform"];
        _escala = (double)this["escala"];


        //var wantedTemplate = ????

        ......
```

Comment: If you use a `x:Key` you can use the Static Method `FindResource`. I don't know about "nameless" `DataTemplates`. Sorry

Comment: @Tico it is fundamental that you don't put a key in a DataTemplate IF you wand it to load automatically (as opposed to explicitly) for a given Type. If I put a breakpoint, I can see the implicit key, only don't know how to access it, see my edit.

Comment: When I use `DataTemplates`it's only with XAML, never did it with code behind. But I do apply resources using the method mentioned above. Good question, I'll be watching this thread.

Comment: As you mentioned in your Edit, DataTemplates with just DataType mentioned but no key will have an implicit key created for them. So, for your DataTemplate the key would be `new DataTemplateKey(typeof(TargetViewModel))`

Comment: @sthotakura I cannot thank you enough, the simple line `var wantedTemplate = this[new DataTemplateKey(typeof(TelaColetaViewModel))];` got me what I wanted. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool, it did help you :). Added answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataTemplates` with just `DataType` mentioned but no `x:Key` will have an implicit key created for them. So, essentially to get to your DataTemplate, all you need to do is Create a DataTemplate Key and use it an indexer parameter for your `ResourceDictionary`

Sample Code below:

```
new DataTemplateKey(typeof(TargetViewModel));
```

Comment: that is awesome.  Was really hoping to find a datatemplate using the DataType. Thanks

Comment: You are genius! This also working in xaml. `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource {DataTemplateKey {x:Type local:MyType}}}"...`.